# How to remove all friends in Google+ at once

Tags: google-plus

I just found out that I have a massive fake friends list in my account. I have more than 4k friends, and it’s hard to remove them one by one. Is there a way to mass-remove them? And if yes, how?

Comment: Simplest way is probably to just delete the Circle that they're in.

Comment: Might be a good time to check if there was a strange login to your account... and change the password!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In the **Circles** section in Google+ we can see all the circles we added our friends. once we click one of that circle its showing all the friends in that circle , as well as following edit and delete option for that circle. Delete the circle, it removes everyone in that circle

[image]